# I need to use html code inside java class

Tags: java, html, sql

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class View {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection connect =SPACE_DBController.SPACE_getConnection();
        stmt = connect.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM SPLD_License_Table1 WHERE (SPLD_LicenseActiveStatus <> 5 OR SPLD_LicenseActiveStatus IS NULL)";
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    }
}
```

//I established a connection to database and executed a query.

After I fetch the rows from the database, I need to display them in a page with some styling. I need to use html, css and js in between. How can I achieve this?

Like in php we use

```
$temp =  sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {
    echo" 
        <th>$key</th>
        <th>$value</th>";
}
```

I need to read all the rows and every column in each row.

Comment: don't have a JSP page? where do you want to show this output?

Comment: In a Command-Line Application? Use XSLT to transform the data into an HTML Page, save it to disc and start a browser to show it.

Comment: @Fildor Save this person some pain and don't suggest XSLT. It's much easier to reate a page template and fill it with the data, either by hand or with a templating framework like Freemarker

Comment: @AdriaanKoster Well I guess that's a matter of taste but your suggestion is of course good advice, too.

Comment: @Fildor XSLT is most suited to transform XML. OP's app does not seem to use XML...

Comment: @AdriaanKoster Meh, I guess you are right. Some reporting tool may also be better suited than XSLT. Rachana: I hereby retract my suggestion to use XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Freemarker for this.

Create a data model:

```
Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<>();
root.put("userName", "Andy");
root.put("licenseName", "Hunting vampires between 23pm and 2am");
root.put("licenseExpirationDate", new Date());
```

Create a file `/templates/license.ftlh` with the template like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Licenses</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Licenses for ${userName}!</h1>
  <p>License ${licenseName} will expire on ${licenseExpirationDate}
</body>
</html>
```

Create freemarker configuration:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_25);
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("/templates"));
cfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
cfg.setLogTemplateExceptions(false);
```

Get a reference to the template:

```
Template temp = cfg.getTemplate("license.ftlh");
```

Write the HTML:

```
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
temp.process(root, out);
```

This example writes the HTML to System.out but if you provide a different OutputStream you can redirect it elsewhere, e.g. to a file or a ServletOutputStream (if you have a web application with Servlets).

EDIT: @Rachana I just read your addition about PHP. Note that Java and PHP are quite different. A PHP app usually consists of pages with mixed PHP instructions and HTML. A PHP page is rendered by a web server with a PHP engine which interprets the page request. Java is not an interpreted language and is not based on pages. A Java app like the one you show above is run on the command line and does not show web pages by itself. In order to show web pages using Java you would typically create a Java web application, commonly packaged in a .war file, which could contain basic Java servlets, JSP's, a Spring MVC application or use one of the other million Java web frameworks. The .war file would be deployed on a web server like Tomcat or Jetty to make the pages accesssible via a browser.

Comment: Thanks @Adriaan koster

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept my answer